# Point Density Percentage Changes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, density, kernel-density, arcgis-10.5

I'm hoping to find out the methodology for mapping increases and decreases in point based occurrences from multiple tables.

Eventual output: A map displaying point density/kernel density increases and decreases of event/location based burglary calls for Police service over three years. (2012, 2013, 2014).

More basically, in a given city, where did burglary calls for service increase or decrease over the 3 years?

The data I have are the three separate years with XY coordinates for the burglary occurrences in excel .csv format.

Field calculating the attributes between two tables is straight forward enough but I wasn't sure how to account for or calculate for an additional table.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. ArcMAP 10.x